# Creating instances of a function via a configuration file

Tags: python, function, class, configuration, instance

We have a configuration file that is read and stored as a dictionary, e.g.

```
config = {'type': A, 'input': {'color': 'red', 'border': 'thick', 'shape': 'square'}}
```

Now we want to use this config object to create an instance of a class, say, `Drawing_Class` with the condition that if the type is 'A', the colour is always blue, and if the type is 'B' the shape is always a circle.

I have written a function to achieve this which seems very unpythonic, and was wondering if there is a better way to achieve my goal? Of course, in the example I've given one could just input the desired colour and shape in the configuration file, but the actual problem is more complex and that can't be achieved.

Here is my function.

```
def drawing_dictionary(type):
    if type == 'A':
        value = config['inputs'].pop('color')
        output = drawing_function(**config['inputs'], colour='blue')
        config['input']['color'] = value

    if type == 'B':
        value = config['inputs'].pop('shape')
        output = drawing_function(**config['inputs'], shape='circle')
        config['input']['shape'] = value

    return output
```

It achieves what I need it to achieve, i.e. creating custom instances based on this configuration file, but in a way that seems very inelegant. Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: may be this way: `import copy
local_config = copy.deepcopy(config)
if type == 'A':
    local_config['input']['color'] = 'blue'
if type == 'B':
    local_config['inputs']['shape'] = 'circle'
output = drawing_function(**local_config)`

Comment: This is very unclear. If `type` is 'A', you are removing value `config['inputs']['color']` and assigning that value to `config['input']['color']` when `config['input']` doesn't exist, so that is clearly an error. Regardless, you seem to be wanting to ignore whatever color is in the configuration and use 'blue' and then put back what was the original configured color. Right? But you don't say why you need to do that. If for type 'A' the color is always 'blue', why don't you just have 'blue' in the configuration to begin with?

Comment: what does drawing_function look like? Is it creating a functor or is it just running a function? You say you want instances of a function aren't you just calling a function?

Comment: @Booboo The reason that I can't just have blue in the configuration file is because, 'type' in the configuration file actually represents a .csv file, which contains time-dependant information on what Type we're actually working with. At one time it could be Type A and one time Type B, I tried to boil down the problem to it's essence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like to use `dict`s to take the place of potentially-large if-elif blocks, so the first thing I would do is to create a lookup for the type names, containing the field name and default value for each type.

```
types = {
    "A": ("color", "blue"),
    "B": ("shape", "circle"),
}
```

I would also recommend copying the contents of the config table, rather than modifying it. This will keep you from accidentally modifying it, and also makes the function re-entrant. Here's my version:

```
def drawing_dictionary(typename):
    key, default = types[typename]
    kwargs = config["inputs"].copy()
    kwargs[key] = default
    return drawing_function(**kwargs)
```

With this implementation, supporting a new type is as simple as adding a row in `types`, rather than defining a new `if` block.

Comment: Thank you, and how would you handle cases where you're returning different objects based on type? E.g. if Type A return drawing_a(**kwargs) and if Type B return drawing_b(**kwargs)

Adding to the dictionary in this case i.e.:

`
types = {
    "A": ("color", "blue", drawing_a(**kwargs)),
    "B": ("shape", "circle", drawing_b(**kwargs)),
}
`

wouldn't really make sense right because kwargs isn't defined at that point

Comment: you could include `drawing_a` and `drawing_b` in the `types` entry, and then unpack it as something like `key, default, drawing_func = types[typename]`, then call it as `drawing_func(**kwargs)`

Comment: in some cases dictionaries are nicer than if elif statements, but they do have their downsides. For one you now have to handle an exception if you get data of any type that isn't contained in the dictionary and the dictionary is not immediately obvious in the drawing_dictionary function (though you could just move it there) If you're using python 3.10 or newer a match case statement is more expressive and functions like the dictionary approach. Since the type value only overrides one argument all the dict copying seems excessive to me but likely unimportant if this code isn't called much.

Answer (score 1):

I asked a question about drawing_function but figured I'd put some things down in an answer and update as necessary.

First off do not name a variable type as while it isn't a reserved keyword in python it is a built in function that allows you to determine the type of an object.

Second you say you want to create an instance of a function, are you talking about a functor? Is drawing_function a class? or are you just calling a function with different arguments depending on a config file (this is what your code seems to indicate and what I have assumed)?

The other code in your project will have an impact on the argument list you want to use and how you want to move data around so that the function gets the correct arguments. Your example code looks like you've made config a global variable which I would not recommend.

What if the config file has extra values in it or is missing values? You'd cause an exception I've added a theoretical validation routine.

Some recommended changes to your example code:

```
def drawing_dictionary(config):
    config = validate_config(config) #remove values you don't understand
    #and confirm all the values you need are present set type to 'Error' 
    #if something is wrong
    if config['type'] == 'Error':
        handle_error()#maybe set a default config?
    else: #this assumes you can't fix the config
        return drawing_function(**config['inputs'],config_type=config['type'])

    return some_sort_of_error_value_or_throw_exception
```

inside of drawing_function you will have all the values in the config['inputs'] unpacked so you'll have a variable named colour and one names shape then you can handle the changes by type in that function to ensure it always happens and without changing the config dictionary:

```
if config_type == 'A':
    colour = 'blue'
elif config_type == 'B':
    shape = 'circle'
```

You could also swap out the if elif stuff for [a match case statement](https://www.pythonpool.com/match-case-python/) if you're using python 3.10 or newer.

Comment: Yes sorry, drawing function is a class, I've edited the original post to account for this mistake. Config is also not a global variable, I just simplified the code to ask the question without overcomplicating things with additional classes. The config file should not have extra values, and if it has missing values the class will be initiated with default values specified in it's __init__ method. Would it be best practice to include a validator anyways?  Thanks

Comment: I guess it depends on how you know that the config file will not have extra values. Omitted values don't matter if you have defaults you're effectively doing part of the validation as part of creating the class. If you know the files are good because you're validating them somewhere else then you already have a validator, if not you really should have one in case your assumptions about them being correct change in the future. Since the only difference between the classes you create is how you handle default variables I think you should just move that logic into the constructor as per my answer

Comment: if you're already effectively validating things somewhere else then there is no need at all for the drawing_dictionary function. The constructor can do all the work seamlessly if it knows the type that is being used to create it. If the type significantly affects the functioning of the classes (I don't think it does) you could use an if elif or match construct to make different classes depending on type but if it's just the same code with different data I can't think of any reason to do it. The key is making your code and architecture easy to understand and reason about.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you have a hierarchy of configurations with the global configuration "if `A` then `color=blue`, if `B` then `shape=circle`" taking precedence over the configuration file. Such a hierarchy can be modeled with the help of [`collections.ChainMap`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.ChainMap), see the following example:

```py
from collections import ChainMap


GLOBAL_CONFIG = {
    'A': dict(color='blue'),
    'B': dict(shape='circle'),
}


def drawing_dictionary(config):
    return drawing_function(**ChainMap(
        GLOBAL_CONFIG.get(config['type'], {}),
        config['input'],
    ))


def drawing_function(**kwargs):
    import pprint
    pprint.pprint(kwargs)


drawing_dictionary({'type': 'A', 'input': {'color': 'red', 'border': 'thick', 'shape': 'square'}})
drawing_dictionary({'type': 'B', 'input': {'color': 'red', 'border': 'thick', 'shape': 'square'}})
```